# Optimize code for string split and extraction

Tags: matlab

I have a code where the overall aim is the extract two numbers from a string.

I get the string located in a cell array. To easy this example I have made the string in the `test` below in my code. I want to extract `1400` in one cell and the 2 in a second cell. The code I have made is working fine, but I think it can be optimized (speed and condensed) a lot. Does any of you have any suggestions?

Code:

```
test{1,1}='1:1400 og 2-fold'
FD1=test{1,1};
C = strsplit(FD1);
C2 = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,strrep(C,':',' '),'un',0));
C3 = cell2mat(C(1,3));
C3=strsplit(C3,'-');
Dilut1=C2(1,2);
Fold1=str2double(C3(1,1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your general structure. For this case, you can split the string at colon, space and dash by using:

```
A = strsplit(test{1,1},{':',' ','-'});
```

and then simply extract the two numbers as the second and fourth element

```
Dilut1=str2num(A{2});
Fold1 = str2num(A{4});
```

But as said it really comes down to your general structure. The more cases you have to account for the longer the code.

Thus it would maybe be better if you could write out something like

```
test{1,1}='1 dilute 1400 fold 2';
```

Then you could split at spaces, and search for the word you are interested in and the next string is then the number, ie

```
A = strsplit(test{1,1});
Dilute = str2num(A{circshift(strcmp(A,'dilute'),1)})
Fold = str2num(A{circshift(strcmp(A,'fold'),1)})
```